# Multi-class feature selection using a SVM and rfe in the caret package

Tags: r, r-caret

I am trying to use the `rfe` function from the `caret` package to run a feature selection on 400 variables belonging to about 50 different classes, with a total of 8000 samples. If I subset my data to about 5 classes and 10 variables, everything works well. However, when I include my entire dataset, R runs for about 32 hours before I get a warning saying that the `R GUI has stopped working`. I tried subsetting my data to 100 variables and 1000 samples, and the same happened. I tried using a completely different dataset of 44 variables and roughly 3000 samples belonging to 44 classes. Yet after a day or so, R becomes unresponsive and shuts down. I have tried the same code on the `iris` data set for reproducability:

```
iris$Species <- as.factor(as.character(iris$Species))
IND.svm <- rfe(iris[,-1],iris$Species,
               sizes = c(2, 5, 10,30),
               rfeControl = rfeControl(functions = caretFuncs,
                                       verbose = FALSE,number = 2000),
                                 method = "svmRadial")
```

I am running Windows 7 so I cannot use the recommended `doMC` package. I have used the latest 64-bit R version, on a machine with a 32G RAM. Still with no success. Is there something I am overlooking here?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the issue is related the not being able to compute variable importance for SVMs via `varImp()`. You may have to write your own `rank()` function.

Comment: @ David, Thanks a million for the insight. Would it be possible to give a small example or point me in the direction where I can find an example. I honestly, don't feel competent enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that the problem is that you are doing **2000** bootstrap samples. Let's say that the argument `tuneLength` has a value of `T` and you are testing 5 subset sizes. For these specifications, you are fitting `10000*T` SVM models for a data set with 8000 samples and 400 variables.

Maybe I low-ball it, but I don't usually do more than 50 resamples (unless the training set is really small). You are basically trying to estimate the mean here (unlike more traditional uses of the bootstrap) and 25 or 50 should be enough, especially for that sample size.

Remember, `rfe` is replicated the entire feature selection process for each resample, so the computations really add up.

Max

Comment: Thanks topepo, makes sense. But I have a trial running with just 5 bootstrap samples, and 24 hours later it is still running. I will have to give David's solution a try, just that I dont know how to use `varIMP` in the 'rfe' function.